# var argument of lists as method argument

Tags: java

I have a unknown number of lists (two in my example but it can vary):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MM, dd");
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(new Employee(100, "Abe Adams", sdf
            .parse("2009, 12, 1"), 10000.00));
    employees.add(new Employee(101, "Betty Barnes", sdf
            .parse("2010, 11, 1"), 11000.00));
    employees.add(new Employee(102, "Caleb Crown", sdf
            .parse("2011, 10, 1"), 12000.00));
    employees.add(new Employee(103, "Dirk Daniels", sdf
            .parse("2012, 09, 1"), 13000.00));

    Date date = new Date();
    List<ObjectTest> objects = new ArrayList<ObjectTest>();
    objects.add(new ObjectTest("name",date,10.0));
    objects.add(new ObjectTest("name2",date,20.0));
```

and I would like to use them as arg in a memthod

```
  oReport.writeReportToExcel(employees,objects);
```

with

```
   public <T> void writeReportToExcel(List <T> ... varArrayData  )    {
               ...
   }
```

I have to use var args parameters but the compiler rejects the code
What needs to be changed ?

The message of the compiler is

```
method writeReportToExcel in class Bean2Excel cannot be applied to given types;
required: List<T>[]
found: List<Employee>, List<ObjectTest>
reason: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
inferred: ObjectTest
equality constraint(s): ObjectTest, Employee
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T> wirteReportToExcel(List<T> ...)
```

EDIT FOR THE SOLUTION (it may be a dirty way)

```
    Bean2Excel oReport = new Bean2Excel();
    List recapList = new ArrayList();
    recapList.add(employees);
    recapList.add(objects);

    oReport.writeReportToExcel(recapList);
```

And as suggested I removed the generics

```
 public void writeReportToExcel(List datas)    {

    try {
        Bean2Excel oReport = new Bean2Excel();

        for (int i = 0;i<datas.size();i++){

            List data = (List)datas.get(i);
          ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the message of the compiler?

Comment: Are these `List`s also going to be of a different type as well? If so, you'll have to specify a common supertype instead of `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<T> should be a specified type in a method. Employee or ObjectTest here, for example. 
But once you defined 2 different types in a method, and try to apply to List<T>[]  named varArrayData,  compile will refuse to do, for it cannot make sure T means Employee.class or ObjectTest.class.

If you really want to use var args, remove <T> mark in method signature might works:

```
public void writeReportToExcel(List ... varArrayData  )    {
           ...
}
```

Or you can put the type define to the class leave:

```
public class Bean2Excel<T>{


public void writeReportToExcel(List<T> ... varArrayData  )    {
           ...
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: as you suggested I removed the generics mark, it is without any doubt, a dirty way, but it works

Comment: and yes it has helped !

Answer (score 2):

the arguments are of different types, T. You could remove the generic definition o rmake them implement a common interface.

Do you have to use var args ?

Comment: they can be any type, and yes, it is necessary that I use var args, unless it is impossible to do so

Answer (score 1):

As said, i would create a common interface, let's say `WritableToExcel` or something, then use wildcards:

```
public void writeReportToExcel(List<? extends WritableToExcel>... varArrayData) { }
```

Now you can read from the lists inside your method, and call methods from `WritableToExcel` to write your table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common base class for the types that can go in the lists.

If `Employee` and `ObjectTest` inherit from the same base class, it should work.

Comment: No.  If `X` is a superclass of `Employee`, then `List<X>` will not be a supertype of `List<Employee>`.